# Syntax of a language in BNF, how to indicate the "other similar" options

Tags: syntax, bnf, ebnf

I'm tryting to write a small language syntax using BNF style. I came to an option like this:

`option  ::=  'option1' | 'option2' | 'read' | 'write' | etc`

The first four options are as example of what values the `option` can have, but I can't enumerate all of them and nor I can group them. Instead, I thought to use something like `etc`, but I don't know if a syntax can have it. Any idea how these options can be shown, what to write instead of `etc`?

Thank you!

Comment: Your question implies that you can't see how to define `etc` as a non-terminal in its own right, and that a production rule such as `etc ::= identifier` (assuming a usual sort of definition of `identifier` itself) is not satisfactory.  But I'm more puzzled by your attempts to write a *small language* with a list of options which you can't write down.  Why not ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark , Thanks a lot! Yes, that's what I want to acieve.The reason is that, I have a list of options which are already realized in the language, but in case that the language evolves, some other options are possible and desired too, so I want to make this explicit also in the syntax.